# When i click the capture Button 2nd time "Error: DP_Device_Failure" Using DPUru 5100

Tags: c#, fingerprint, biometrics, error-messaging, digital-persona-sdk

I am using Digital Persona Uru 5100. When i tried to click the captur button for the first time it works correctly. But after closing the capture window and clicking again on capture button it generates error 
[Error Screenshot Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Kx33F.png)

After clicking ok to this error 2nd error window popup

[2nd Error Screenshot Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/87RzD.png)

can anyone tell me the solution of this problem?
I am using code below to Open Reader

```
public bool OpenReader()
    {
        reset = false;
        Constants.ResultCode result = Constants.ResultCode.DP_DEVICE_FAILURE;

        // Open reader
        result = CurrentReader.Open(Constants.CapturePriority.DP_PRIORITY_COOPERATIVE);

        if (result != Constants.ResultCode.DP_SUCCESS)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Error:  " + result);
            reset = true;
            return false;
        }

        return true;
    }
```

Comment: Maybe you don't need to open it the second time because it is already open

Comment: i am developing an attendance management system. And i am getting this error while opening Capture form for enroll a fingerprint. 
I have to enroll employees fingerprints so i have to open and close this form again and again..